# Prove that $ \forall X \in \mathcal{B}([0,+\infty]), f_{\alpha}^{-1}(X) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory

We have $f_{\alpha} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ defined by $f_{\alpha}(x) = \dfrac{ \sqrt{|x|} }{1-x} 1_{[0,\alpha]}(x)$.

I would like to prove that :
$$ \forall X \in \mathcal{B}([0,+\infty]), f_{\alpha}^{-1}(X) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$$.

Do you know how to do it ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is $f_\alpha$ defined at $0$?

Comment: Oh sorry ! $\alpha \in [0,1]$.

Comment: If $x=1$, you are dividing by $0$.